# How to save an input to use it later ( I've been trying using Shared preference)?

Tags: java, android, input, save, android-phone-call

The app is getting an input number and has a button that makes the call. I want to save the input for later use and have tried used Shared preference.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button myButton = null;
    EditText numberCall = null;
    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The button for making the call:

```
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

I want to save numberCall!

```
    numberCall = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

asking for permission

```
    if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            OnCallBtnClicked();
        }
    });
}
```

making the call

```
private void OnCallBtnClicked() {

    Integer num = Integer.valueOf(numberCall.getText().toString());
    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +"0"+num));
    startActivity(call);

    }

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What didn't work with SharedPreferences? Because what I understand is that you want to save a number and it will definitively be the way to go.

Comment: I want to save it so next time the user uses the app it will be already set. Could you help me? Maybe an example or how it should look? I tried like I said and nothing so far. (I am new in Android developing)

Comment: So when a call is made, save the number. When restarting app the number should already be in the EditText is that what you want? You can read about SharedPreferences [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), it will work for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preference would be the easiest solution .change your  `OnCallBtnClicked` method to this :

```
 private void OnCallBtnClicked() {
        Integer num = Integer.valueOf(numberCall.getText().toString());
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +"0"+num));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
     editor.putString("Phone", "0"+num);

     editor.commit();

      startActivity(call);

        }
```

to get the value you save  , try this :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("Phone", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String phone= prefs.getString("Phone", "No value defined");//"No valuedefined" is the default value.

}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: tried, didnt work.
where should i put the second code? "to get the value..."

Comment: @TsurYohananov . if i understood you well , you need it the next time the user open the app . so my best guess would be `onCreate` method of your main Activity

Answer (score 0):

@TsurYohananov 
If you want to add database then it is easy to get value which was stored by user

Firebase database has the capability to provide this functionality.
There is much more video on youtube to get a reference.